# Skip shell commands when script is executed by Ansible

Tags: bash, shell, ansible, sh

I have a shell script that does a lot of stuff. There is a section of authenticating the GitHub package registry. This section prompts for username and password. When I executed the bash script using Ansible, it's stuck there with a message "Escalation succeeded". What I want to do is define the registry login in ansible, which of course is straight forward. That's not an issue. The problem I have is I'd like the GitHub registry command in the bash script to be skipped when the script is run via ansible. Something like:

```
if [[ "$ANSIBLE" == "true" ]]; then
skip
fi
```

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Can you get parent process id maybe? (Wild guess from non-user of Ansible)

Comment: Why don't you simply detect that you're already logged in rather than detecting ansible ? An other approach would be to not detect anything, not login before and provide the necessary login info from ansible using [`expect`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html)

Comment: @Zeitounator I can provide the necessary login from ansible but the script isn't only used in ansible. Some users just run the script normally in their machines without using ansible.

Comment: @MarkSetchell haven't tried that.

Comment: This is why I suggest expect. So ansible uses the script exactly as a user except you automatically provide from ansible the login information. No changes to your script at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to set [environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html#setting-the-environment-and-working-with-proxies) for Ansible tasks. For example

```yaml
    - name: Shell script that does a lot of stuff
      command: my_script.sh
      environment:
        my_script_in_ansible: "true"
```

Then use the variable in the script. For example

```sh
ANSIBLE=${my_script_in_ansible:-false}

if [[ "$ANSIBLE" == "true" ]]; then
    skip
fi
```

It's a good idea to avoid potential conflicts of environment names.

<sup>(not tested)</sup>